# How to listen for Exceptions in Android?

Tags: android, exception

Some of the analytics packages (for instance, [Flurry](http://flurry.com)) will listen for [Exception](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Exception.html)s and log them w/o actually catching them. How are they doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) and the respective [`Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) which receives the `Thread` and `Throwable` involved.

Comment: Thanks... I ended up finding another question which had a pretty good answer thanks to your help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application/755151#755151

Answer (score 1):

Probably via [`Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)).

Comment: What if you want to globally catch exceptions:  Is this possible: See my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740843/android-global-error-handling-and-reporting-activity