# How to change Exception message, "The application ... has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again later.”

Tags: android, exception, crash, message

Is there any way to modify the generic Android Exception message "The application ... has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again later.” to display something more meaningful to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about implementing your own  UncaughtExceptionHandler.

See this question for some ideas:

[How do I obtain crash-data from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application)