# Change design of "app closed unexpectedly"

Tags: android

How do I change the design when "app closed unexpectedly". I saw it on whatsapp and I would like to implement it my app. I would like to do the design so users are able to send a report. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement your own UncaughtExceptionHandler.

See the below [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673497/how-to-change-exception-message-the-application-has-stopped-unexpectedly) for a few ideas? It seems like a good starting point.