# How to instruct users to report a bug in Android

Tags: android, bug-reporting

How do you instruct users to report a bug in Android? Any advice or tips?

I'd like to get send detailed instructions to my users to get the most of their bug report. I know there are various apps that send bug reports from the device and I was wondering how other Android developers deal with this.

Comment: I'm just starting out with Android, so I don't know the answer. But I strongly suspect you will get several bug reports in your Android Market reviews, even if you tell people not to do that. So check your reviews fairly frequently.

Comment: Not really asking about where to find bug reports. The question is more about what to tell users who want to report them. (and hope you have a blast with Android!)

Comment: Right. I'm just saying, after you give your users instructions, don't be surprised if they don't follow them!

Comment: Possible duplicate question ... The answer to your question lies in this SO question: [How Do I Obtain Crash Data From My Android Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking Gilbert's advice into account, I decided to create my own app. I hereby present you: [Bug Reporter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.robotmedia.bugreporter).

It allows users to send you a report with device information and optional logcat. It also supports intent extras to customize its behavior if case you want to launch it from your app.

Comment: The bug reporter link is broken

Comment: Is there a source it can be downloaded from for users that don't have Google Play?

Answer (score 6):

A bug reporting SDK such as [Instabug](https://instabug.com) can let you achieve that.

[image: Pop up message instructing users how to report a bug in your live app]

As you can see, it displays, by default, a welcome message to your users 10 seconds after opening the app. It displays instructions on how to invoke Instabug depending on the invocation method you're using (A button or a shake gesture).

After signing up and including the library in your code, you can switch between different display messages. Use either of the following lines depending on whether you're in beta or production.

```
Instabug.setWelcomeMessageState(WelcomeMessage.State.BETA);
Instabug.setWelcomeMessageState(WelcomeMessage.State.LIVE);
```

Each bug report contains various information about device details, network logs, console logs, view hierarchy inspection, and visual reproduction steps.

---

For full disclosure, I work at Instabug. Let me know if I can help.

Answer (score 4):

There are solutions for instrumenting the application in a way that will collect contextual information and allow the user to provide in-app feedback. Either by shaking the phone or some other trigger like a menu option.

Here is a "currently free" offering from IBM called Mobile Quality Assurance, that will instrument the application so that as a user uses the application contextual information is collected as they use the app. When they want to provide feedback or submit a bug, they can shake the phone and it will capture the screen at the time, give them a form to enter additional information and then submit the screenshot, contextual information and comments to the testing portal.

Here's a link for more info on [MQA](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobilequalitybeta/entry/what_is_mobile_quality_assurance?cmp=exp&cpb=mqa&ct=SO&cr=exp&ccy=US)

Answer (score 1):

You can do what google does with their new maps application on iPhone.  When you're using the app and shake the phone (which users do when they're frustrated or something isn't working) you can pop up a screen that asks if something is wrong and is a form for bug submission that they can choose to fill out.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't Android specific, but you could have a bug reporting screen in your application that sends the information your customers type, along with any system information you wish to capture, to your web server.  Alternatively, the application could email you with the information.

Comment: This is what I was thinking of doing. I was wondering if there's an existing app that handles this already and that can be launched using an intent from mine.

Comment: If there isn't, make a generalized app.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries you can integrate to do this job, you don't need to develop a solution yourself. For example, I'm using [blit feedback](http://www.blitfeedback.com). With this library you can take snapshots, draw on them and add some comments. I've configured it to send reports by email, but if you have an issue tracker you can connect it too.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered this question a lot late. There are answers given but the products mentioned or the techniques are quite old now. Adding the tool that we have been working on - [Bugclipper](http://www.bugclipper.com)

This tool let's your users report issues from with-in the app Android or iOS and you can add/annotate screenshots, create screen recordings with voice and also get the crash logs.

p.s. - I am one of the co-founders.