# Android crash reporting library (pre Froyo)

Tags: android, crash-reports

Do you know any crash reporting library for Android?

I don't want to spend a lot of time to write my own reporting system.
The output can be send to the email or some kind of server.

I know that Google introduced crash reporting in Froyo, but I want something for older versions of the system.

---

Let's sum up the answers:

- [android-remote-stacktrace](http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/) - sends raports to mail or php script
- [acra](http://acra.googlecode.com/) - sends reports to google docs
- [Android Error Reporter](https://github.com/tomquist/Android-Error-Reporter) - sends reports via HTTP post request

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is what you are looking for: [android-remote-stacktrace](http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/)
It sends an email / calls a php script when your application crashes and sends the logcat output. Quite simple to use and very useful!

*Remotely log unhandled exceptions in your Android applications*

Comment: I'm not aware of any others, this was only one I could find about a month ago when I was looking. Probably unlikely to see too much development in this area because as you pointed out froyo supports crash reporting.

Comment: I did those things but I could not understand which email address is this library going to use to send the crash report to me? Thanks

Comment: Is this still valid in 2019? For example, http://trace.nullwire.com is down. Thanks in advance for an update!

Answer (score 12):

You can also try out a service done by my company just for that purpose (and a bit more) http://apphance.com . It allows not only to get crashes, but also logs, screenshots whenever tester reports a problem. It reports it to the cloud and lets developer to browse through the sessions/logs/crashes/issue reports using a useful web panel.

It is more targeted for testing part, but soon there will also be a production-version available. It is also cross-platform - not only Android but also iOS and soon more.

Disclaimer: I am CTO of Polidea, company behind Apphance, co-creator of the app.

Answer (score 9):

You can also try [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com). BugSense collects and analyzes all crash reports and gives you meaningful and visual reports. It's free, used by big applications (with more than 10.000.000 users) and it's only 1 line of code in order to integrate.

Disclaimer: I am a co-founder

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an Error-Reporting Library for my own project which is very easy to integrate. It allows you to send error reports to a http server (similar to android-remote-stacktrace). It's open source and can be downloaded from github: https://github.com/tomquist/Android-Error-Reporter

Answer (score 0):

Android is all open source, so perhaps you could just extract that part of Froyo and add it to your app as though it were a third-party library. I don't know how easy or feasible that would be, but if it works for you, let us know!

http://source.android.com/source/download.html

Comment: Android is not all open source. The crash handler is most likely not open source because it depends on the Market.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't got time for such work :-(

Comment: No need to goto all this effort, as it a library has already been written to do it. See my answer above.

Comment: @alexanderblom : I didn't know that. Disappointing. I guess the Market isn't strictly part of Android, arguably.