# How to get Android crash logs?

Tags: android, logging, crash

I have an app that is not in the market place (signed with a debug certificate), but would like to get crash log data, whenever my application crashes. Where can I find a log of why my app crashed?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

If your app is being downloaded by other people and crashing on remote devices, you may want to look into an Android error reporting library (referenced in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378550/android-crash-reporting-library-pre-froyo)).  If it's just on your own local device, you can use `LogCat.`  Even if the device wasn't connected to a host machine when the crash occurred, connecting the device and issuing an `adb logcat` command will download the entire logcat history (at least to the extent that it is buffered which is usually a loooot of log data, it's just not infinite).  Do either of those options answer your question?  If not can you attempt to clarify what you're looking for a bit more?

Comment: can you detail how to use the adb logcat command? Do i run this inside the /SDK/tools directory? Are there any flags I should note ? etc.

Comment: @jesses.co.tt Yep, just run `adb logcat` from whatever directory adb is located in.  Alternatively you can use the SDK tools included in the Eclipse plugin

Comment: Crashlytics is the best remote exception logging software I've ever used. It goes out in all my apps, check it out.

Comment: adb.exe is located in `$SDK_DIR/platform-tools/`. To show error: `.\adb.exe logcat -v time  *:E`

Answer (score 102):

You can try this from the console:

```
adb logcat --buffer=crash
```

More info on this option:

```
adb logcat --help

...

  -b <buffer>, --buffer=<buffer>         Request alternate ring buffer, 'main',
                  'system', 'radio', 'events', 'crash', 'default' or 'all'.
                  Multiple -b parameters or comma separated list of buffers are
                  allowed. Buffers interleaved. Default -b main,system,crash.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it shows the crash logs in realtime! Really helpful.

Comment: This may be related to specific shell, but on zsh you need to indicate buffer type with quotes

Answer (score 71):

The way to do this is to implement the `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` interface and pass it to `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` at the beginning of your Activity's `onCreate()`.                                                                              Here is the implementation class `TopExceptionHandler`.

```
public class TopExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;
    private Activity app = null;

    public TopExceptionHandler(Activity app) {
        this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        this.app = app;
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        StackTraceElement[] arr = e.getStackTrace();
        String report = e.toString()+"\n\n";
        report += "--------- Stack trace ---------\n\n";
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            report += "    "+arr[i].toString()+"\n";
        }
        report += "-------------------------------\n\n";

        // If the exception was thrown in a background thread inside
        // AsyncTask, then the actual exception can be found with getCause

        report += "--------- Cause ---------\n\n";
        Throwable cause = e.getCause();
        if(cause != null) {
            report += cause.toString() + "\n\n";
            arr = cause.getStackTrace();
            for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                report += "    "+arr[i].toString()+"\n";
            }
        }
        report += "-------------------------------\n\n";

        try {
            FileOutputStream trace = app.openFileOutput("stack.trace", 
                                                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            trace.write(report.getBytes());
            trace.close();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
        // ...
        }

        defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);
    }
}
```

Note  We let the Android framework's defaultUEH to handle it.

At the top of your Activity register an instance of above class like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new TopExceptionHandler(this));
...
```

This handler saves the trace in a file. When `ReaderScope` restarts next time, it detects the file and prompts the user if he/she wants to email it to the developer.

To Email the Stack Trace, execute following code to pack it in an email.

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(ReaderScopeActivity.this.openFileInput("stack.trace")));
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        trace += line+"\n";
    }
} catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    // ...
} catch(IOException ioe) {
    // ...
}

Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String subject = "Error report";
String body = "Mail this to appdeveloper@gmail.com: " + "\n" + trace + "\n";

sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"readerscope@altcanvas.com"});
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

ReaderScopeActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Title:"));

ReaderScopeActivity.this.deleteFile("stack.trace");
```

Or you can also use ACRA Error Reporting System.Just Include the ACRA.jar in your project libs and use the below code snippet before your launcher activity class declaration

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", mailTo = "abc@gmail.com;def@yahoo.com", mode = ReportingInteractionMode.SILENT)
```

or You can try this from console:-

```
adb logcat -b crash
```

Comment: Won't the line defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e); call the method uncaughtException() infinitely?

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron no - it will just transfer same Throwable to top level handler.

Comment: A wonderful find for me. Have implemented with data getting logged to Google spreadsheet. Made my life easier for debugging.

Answer (score 48):

This is from http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Debug-adb-logcat-Command-Debugging.html

You can use adb:

```
adb logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:S
```

Comment: 'adb logcat -d CRASH:E *:S*'

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Eclipse, make sure you use debug and not run.
Make sure you are in the debug perspective (top right)
You may have to hit 'Resume' (F8) a few times for the log to print.
The crash log will be in the Logcat window at the bottom- double click for fullscreen and make sure you scroll to the bottom. You'll see red text for errors, the crash trace will be something like

```
09-04 21:35:15.228: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dazlious.android.helloworld/com.dazlious.android.helloworld.main}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268) 
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at com.example.android.helloworld.main.onCreate(main.java:13)
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     ... 11 more
```

The important parts for this one are

```
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
09-04 21:35:15.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778):     at com.example.android.helloworld.main.onCreate(main.java:13)
```

those tell us it was an array out of bounds exception on on line 13 of main.java in the onCrate method.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Apphance. This is a cross-platform service (now mainly Android, iOS with other platforms on their way) which allows to debug remotely any mobile device (Android, iOS now - others under development). It's much more than just a crashlog, in fact it is much more: logging, reporting of problems by testers, crashlogs. It takes about 5 minutes to integrate. Currently you can request for access to closed beta.

Disclaimer: I am CTO of Polidea, a company behind Apphance and co-creator of it.

Update: Apphance is no longer closed beta!
Update 2: Apphance is available as part of http://applause.com offering

Comment: I just tried apphance and like it. The docs missed a key point when integrating apphance lib into your app; with the latest version of the Eclipse ADT, you must put the apphance.jar in the `libs` directory as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9916751/9648) SO answer explains. [This github commit](https://github.com/johnnylambada/WorldMap/commit/235ac0461a91a080cca2cdcb7fd2059464165406) shows the changes I needed to make to my WorldMap app to use apphance.

Comment: @HohnnyLambada Thanks for your comment. We have updated the documentation to make this clearer.

Comment: this shouldn't get so many up arrows it costs 10x more than most development budgets ($2,500 a month!)

Comment: apphance is 404 at the date of this comment.

Comment: Correct. It's been bough already long time ago by uTest which then rebranded their whole offering (including Aphhance's feature) to Applause. So now it's http://applause.com/

Answer (score 8):

Here is another solution for Crash Log.

Android market has tool named "Crash Collector"

check following link for more information

http://kpbird.blogspot.com/2011/08/android-application-crash-logs.html

Comment: Does not work on Android 4.1 and later (new permissions to read logs).

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a basic crash reporting tool, try [crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/).

If you want a more advanced reporting tool, Checkout [Gryphonet](http://www.gryphonet.com). It logs all the crashes occured along with the exact line of code that caused the crash along with automated markers that show you the steps the user took prior to the crash and more.

Good luck!

Comment: Crashlytics is good, too, because it's cross-platform for Android, iOS, ...

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution that can help you dump all the logs onto a text file

```
adb logcat -d > logs.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use ACRA from [this](https://github.com/ACRA/acra). Including this library to your projects and configuring it, you could receive (into your email or gdocs) their crash reports. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3):

Use acra crash reporter for android app..[**Acra lib**](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

Answer (score 3):

I have created this library to solve all your problems.
[Crash Reporter is a handy tool to capture all your crashes and log them in device locally](https://github.com/balsikandar/CrashReporter)

Just add this dependency and you're good to go.

```
compile 'com.balsikandar.android:crashreporter:1.0.1'
```

Find all your crashes in device locally and fix them at your convenience.
Crashes are saved using date and time format easy to track. Plus it also provides API for capture Logged Exceptions using below method.

```
CrashRepoter.logException(Exception e)
```

Comment: What is the Java class that you used to get the Crash Logs of a device?

Comment: Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler interface is used to capture all the unhandled crashes. Here is the implementation for the same https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/CrashReporter/blob/master/crashreporter/src/main/java/com/balsikandar/crashreporter/utils/CrashReporterExceptionHandler.java.

Comment: Okay lemme check this...! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1) Plug in Phone through USB (w/ Developer Debugging options enabled)

2) Open Terminal and Navigate to your Android SDK (for Mac):

`cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`

3) Logcat from that directory (in your terminal) to generate a constant flow of logs (for Mac):

`./adb logcat`

4) Open your app that crashes to generate crash logs

5) Ctrl+C to stop terminal and look for the logs associated with the app that crashes.  It may say something like the following:

`AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use library [crashcatcher](https://github.com/netcook/crash-catcher)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for the crash log while your phone is connected to the computer, use the DDMS view in Eclipse and the report is right there in LogCat within DDMS when your app crashes while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

**Base on this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22527672/11239018)**, use this class as replacement of "TopExceptionHandler"

```
class TopExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;
private Activity app = null;
private String line;

public TopExceptionHandler(Activity app) {
    this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    this.app = app;
}

public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {




    StackTraceElement[] arr = e.getStackTrace();
    String report = e.toString()+"\n\n";
    report += "--------- Stack trace ---------\n\n";
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        report += "    "+arr[i].toString()+"\n";
    }
    report += "-------------------------------\n\n";

    // If the exception was thrown in a background thread inside
    // AsyncTask, then the actual exception can be found with getCause

    report += "--------- Cause ---------\n\n";
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    if(cause != null) {
        report += cause.toString() + "\n\n";
        arr = cause.getStackTrace();
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            report += "    "+arr[i].toString()+"\n";
        }
    }
    report += "-------------------------------\n\n";

    try {
        FileOutputStream trace = app.openFileOutput("stack.trace",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        trace.write(report.getBytes());
        trace.close();



        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"kevineyni@gmail.com"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "crash report azar");
        String body = "Mail this to kevineyni@gmail.com: " + "\n" + trace + "\n";
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , body);
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
           // Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }






      //  ReaderScopeActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Title:"));

        //ReaderScopeActivity.this.deleteFile("stack.trace");

    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        // ...
    }

    defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);
}

private void startActivity(Intent chooser) {
}
```

}

.....

> in same java class file (Activity)
>   .....

```
Public class MainActivity.....
```

.....

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new TopExceptionHandler(this));
```

.....

Answer (score -1):

Try Carsh log app from android.

use the [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=crashLog.cutebabyTW) to download app.