# Is there a LOG created when an Android application crashes?

Tags: android, logging

Is there somekind of log (like an OS event log or something) that could maybe give me an idea as to why an application crashes on start?

The specifics (irrlevant to the question itself):
I have recently purchased a copy of Final Fantasy Dimensions for my Android phone (Motorla XT615 with Android 2.3.7) and everytime I click on it I get a flicker (black-screen) and then it goes back to the home screen.

Does anyone have any suggestions or am I way off base with this one?
Thanks,

Comment: Are you an Android app developer?

Comment: Not really the right place to ask your question unless you develop Android apps. The answer, however, is yes. Android has something called logcat which is a circular real-time logging system. You can download various apps from Google Play. I quite like one called CatLog.

Comment: Yeah, the only way viewing the log would really help you is if you were an Android Dev and had the src code right in front of you. But, hey, you never know!

Answer (score 4):

There are apps a user can download from Google Play that can grab log files to be sent to a developer.  For example: [Log Collector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector) and [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat).

**Note:** With Jelly Bean and later, root access is required for an app to access the logs of another app, so the log-grabbing apps listed above may not be useful for the average Android user.

If you have Android development tools available, see [How to get Android crash logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643395/how-to-get-android-crash-logs?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You could read the log using apps such as [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat) or [Log Collector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector), but it probably isn't going to help you find the FC issue, unless you actually had the code for it right in front of you, which you wouldn't have unless you were a dev of the game. But, anyways, good luck!