# Android App not opening after adding Push notification plugin on ionic 2

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ionic 2 Angular 2 and Typescript to make an app. I recently integrated the push notification plugin and had rough time making it to the `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` but i managed to do so after replacing some lines in `project.properties`. But after deploying to device the app doesn't open and displays the `App has stopped` message the moment i open it.

Here is my code :

**Project.properties**

```
target=android-25
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib

cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.0
cordova.system.library.4=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.14@aar
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0
cordova.gradle.include.1=phonegap-plugin-push/comvltapp596066-push.gradle
```

**Note :** the target has been android-25 before and it was working fine on my KK Tablet and Lollipop phone.

I don't know what more code  post here but if anything is needed i will post it

So anyone know the problem ?

Comment: I suggest you to use this code (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643395/how-to-get-android-crash-logs/22527672#22527672) to get all the uncaught exceptions.

Comment: i am using Ionic so all my code is in Typescript and that code looks like in java so i can't be using that

Comment: I did find the solution, which was to enable multidex by installing this plugin : `npm i cordova-plugin-multidex` and then adding it to the config.xml like this 
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-multidex" spec="0.1.4" />` (version can change) 
But it still loads horribly slow at first time