# crash logs on android application

Tags: android, logging

I write android application in eclipse and i want to catch the crashes
What the best way to get the crash logs for android app ?

I read about **acra** library  but i dont use gardle its must for this library ?
and if its the best way have i add it to my app?

I try to use crash logs application from google play it was good but the log wasnt much clear maybe there is another application for this ?

some one can help me?

Comment: why aren't you using **Android Studio**? it  is widely used IDE among the android developers

Comment: First of all, don´t use Eclipse. Eclipse is outdated and will not supported anymore (since I guess 2 Years). Use Android Studio to get the full features. Second, please clearify what You mean with crashs? While developing, you don´t need a special tool, it´s everything integrated in Eclipse or Android Studio, you just need to read on the Logcat (Android Monitor). If it´s a published App, you can add the library for example crashlytics:https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install or firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/

Comment: its published App That is we check it on the device

Comment: then you can use one of my suggested libs. I recommend Firebase, it´s Googles librarie and you can do everything with it:https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: and really, change to Android Studio, You will have much less trouble and get the full Android Support....

Comment: I was confused its still in staging envirment- what you suggest its also good for it?

Comment: Every IDE is under development....there are allways things to change and to make better, that´s the way a software is. But Android Studio working absolutely good and is the official Android IDE...

Comment: acra its not well?'

Comment: not used acra until today, so I can´t say it´s good or bad. The thing is, by integrating Firebase you can also use all other features. FireBase is easy to use....

Comment: Can i use it on eclipse? or just in android studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android crash reporting library (pre Froyo)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378550/android-crash-reporting-library-pre-froyo)

Answer (score 1):

Best way for catching crashes for published apps is [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install)

Also you can use Crashes & ANRs in Google Play Developer Console, but it shows crashes only if users **sent** them

Comment: I was confused its still  in staging  envirment- what you suggest its also good for it?

Comment: @user5993555 you can watch list of **all** crashes on **all** devices. All crash reports include stacktrace and information about devices.