# Global try-catch for a service

Tags: android

I found a solution for a global try-catch in an activity. ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427515/using-global-exception-handling-on-android)) Can I do something similar with a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` is for your entire application. You can call `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` from a `Service` if you wish, instead of from an `Activity`. However, you only need to call it once for your application, in most cases.

Comment: Just to make it clear, do I have to put it in a SomeBaseActivity and make every other activity inherit from it? Or calling it once in my InitialActivity is enough?

Comment: @gisek: Once in your `InitialActivity` is enough, for the lifetime of that process. That being said, you do need to make sure that it will be called no matter how your process is created -- if they might get to your app by means other than `InitialActivity`, you have a problem. This is why many apps, such as those using ACRA, will tend to use a custom `Application` class for this.