# How to catch error 'Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture'

Tags: java, android, bitmap

My android application handles very large Bitmaps. Because of this, I turned hardware-acceleration off on the image views.
However, some users have set the Developer-Option 'Force GPU-Acceleration' turned on. This leads to the error 'Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture'.
If I check the view using isHardwareAccelerated(), it always returns false.

Is there any way to catch the OpenGL-Error 'Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture'?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find something to catch this error?

Answer (score 2):

Bitmap is Composed of Pixels  and you can count the number of pixels in the bitmap matrix ,, set a limit to your number of bitmap  pixels . In OpenGl i can't say , but in general we can easily handle them , also there is a method
    bitmap.inSampleSize();

if you assign

```
Bitmap.inSampleSize()= 1;
```

then the original bitmap pixel will be loaded.

```
Bitmap.inSampleSize()= 2;
```

then the pixels will become half of the original pixel.

```
Bitmap.inSampleSize() = 4
```

then the pixels will become 1/4 of the original pixel .
This way you can reduce the size of the pixels in the bitmap ,
I have done this thing in my program , hopefully it will work with you too.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, but I need the maximum quality. Therefore, I switched Hardware-Acceleration off on this view. However, I just need to know if the user has the "Force GPU-Acceleration" enabled which leads to this error.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with OpenGL on Android and therefore dont know is there is anything special one must do to catch uncaught exceptions or error. You could try to [register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427515/using-global-exception-handling-on-android) a global exception handler and check if you are able to catch the OpenGL error there.

Comment: Thanks for this idea! However, since it isn't an acutal exception, this won't work. The app won't crash or anything, just the view won't draw. I just see the OpenGL-Error message in the debug/warn Log from Logcat.