# Unhandled exception not caught by global exceptionhandler

Tags: android, exception

I got an android app where I set a global exception handler as described here:
[Using Global Exception Handling on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427515/using-global-exception-handling-on-android)

When I'm forcing an exception then I see that it is catched by the handler.

But from time to time I'm still experiencing device freezes when running the app.

The app uses a lot of different threads. But as far as I understand, this should have no influence.

Are there some known limitations on android regarding global exception handling, where exception are not handled by the global handler?

Thanks

Comment: By "freeze" do you mean that the device becomes completely unresponsive?

Comment: yes, from the user perspective. It is still possible to open a shell over adb an apply some commands.

Comment: I don't think it's caused by exception then, more like the app somehow forced the system into a bad place.