# Can I call and execute a method when app is crashing by OS or any other exceptions?

Tags: android, service, crash

I'm having an app which starts BLE session and do its job. But when the app crashed I want to stop the BLE session and stop other BLE services running. Can somebody help me to achieve this?

I tried services and I was able to stop them successfully. But the objects and BLE sessions are defined in few classes are not able to.

Answer (score 0):

This [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19945692/14577209) can be modified to execute a method when an uncaught exception is thrown depending on the thread that your exception occurs.