# unfortunately closed message customization in android

Tags: android, error-handling, user-customization

I want my own message should be showed when my app crashes or stopped working. Or when app crashes,any other activity should be displayed.In that time an Intent should be called

[link](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=unfortunately+stopped&safe=active&client=firefox-a&hs=t74&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&biw=1600&bih=789&noj=1&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=dJNhVK2BLcuGuATN-oLQCw&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg&dpr=1#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=WgsbBAxdy2yHPM%253A%3B7K0H6gblxHko2M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.ekoob.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2012%252F07%252Fapp-has-stopped-crashed-android-nexus-7.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.ekoob.com%252Ffix-crashing-not-working-app-android-nexus-7-11408%252F%3B277%3)

Refer the above link.

Comment: Ever heard of exception handling ?

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427515/using-global-exception-handling-on-android

Comment: can you accept the answer by clicking tick mark below down arrow beside the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler

```
Public class YOURAPPLICATION extends Application
    {
      public void onCreate ()
      {
        // Setup handler for uncaught exceptions.
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
        {
          @Override
          public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
          {
            handleUncaughtException (thread, e);
          }
        });
      }

      public void handleUncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
      {

       //CREATE YOUR ACTIVITY HERE.


      }
```