# Does Android care about exit status code passed to System.exit(...)?

Tags: java, android, exit-code, system.exit

If I kill an Android app with [`System.exit(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)), does it matter what status code I pass? I couldn't find any documentation on whether Android just ignores it or whether certain ones lead to any error messages for example or have any other meaning.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the exit code returned by the process when it finishes; Android however does not care, but know that the error code should never be higher then 255.

Here is a list of standard exit codes - some process may use their own codes.

> 0    Clean Exit
>   1    General Error Catchall
>   2    Misuse of shell builtins
>   126  Command invoked execution error
>   127  Command not found
>   128  Invalid exit argument?
>   130  Termination by Control-C
>   255  Exit status unknown

Comment: +1, these exit codes are listed on the [The Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

Answer (score 3):

Android does not care, no. This is a java thing -- you can use them for your own debugging etc etc.

Here's an example of system exit codes: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-320/include/sysexits.h

But pretty much, anything > 0 means that its an abnormal exit. You can set it to whatever you want, but I'd just stick to 0 unless you're interacting with other things.

It just seems to be the accepted convention.