# start activity in custom UncaughtExceptionHandler class not working any more

Tags: android, android-thread

I used to handle exception errors with this class and pass error as String to another activity for show , but this way not work any more , seems when kill process happened "sag.class" Activity cant launch any more

```
public class ExceptionHandler extends MainActivity implements java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private final Context myContext;

    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    private StringBuilder errorReport;

    public ExceptionHandler(Context context) {
        myContext = context;
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {



        StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
        exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
        System.err.println(stackTrace);

        exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
        errorReport = new StringBuilder();
        errorReport.append("************ CAUSE OF ERROR ************\n\n");
        errorReport.append(stackTrace.toString());

        errorReport.append("\n************ DEVICE INFORMATION ***********\n");

        errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        errorReport.append("Product: ");
        errorReport.append(Build.PRODUCT);
        errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        errorReport.append("\n************ FIRMWARE ************\n");
        errorReport.append("SDK: ");
        errorReport.append(Build.VERSION.SDK);
        errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        errorReport.append("Release: ");
        errorReport.append(Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
        errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        errorReport.append("Incremental: ");
        errorReport.append(Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL);
        errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);


        errorReport.append("App Version: ");
        try {
            errorReport.append(myContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(myContext.getPackageName(), 0).versionName);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);


        prefs = myContext.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (prefs.contains("access_token"))
        {
            errorReport.append(prefs.getString("fname","")+" "+prefs.getString("lname",""));
        }


        Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, sag.class);
        intent.putExtra("error", errorReport.toString());
        myContext.startActivity(intent);

        Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
        System.exit(10);

    }


}
```

so how can start activity in UncaughtExceptionHandler  class with new way ?

Answer (score 0):

try this, please add this code to start new activity

```
Intent startAppIntent = new Intent(this, sag.class);
        startAppIntent.putExtra("error", errorReport.toString());
        startAppIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startAppIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startAppIntent);
        System.exit(1);
```

you can change `this` to `myContext` if `this` doesn't work. Please let us know if this code works for you.

Comment: @erfan I get the same strange behaviour. The Intent is not firing. Did you find solution on this problem? If yes, could you please share it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer : Yes you can start  an activity from `UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

```
fun restartApp(context : Context) {
    val intent = Intent(context, Destination::class.java)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    context.startActivity(intent)
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())
    exitProcess(0)
}
```

you can also find the exit status number in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226842/does-android-care-about-exit-status-code-passed-to-system-exit)