# how to start an activity from UncaughtExceptionHandler in DaggerApplication

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, dagger-2, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I'm facing a similar scenario like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204957/start-activity-in-custom-uncaughtexceptionhandler-class-not-working-any-more) with the same strange behaviour: The intent will not fire, the crash dialog won't be showed either and the app closes by itself after crashing. `Logcat` shows the error like this:

```
E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7512186516213"
and so on....
D/Android Runtime: Shutting down VM
```

How can we start an activity from `UncaughtExceptionHandler` in `DaggerApplication` ?

Here is my code. I'm using the `applicationContext` everywhere and I have registered the `ExceptionDisplay` activity in my `Manifest` file. I'm sure that the `DaggerApplication` can handle this as well as the `Application` class, but I unfortunately can't solve it by myself.

```
class IpunktApp : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> =
        DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(this)

    private lateinit var defaultUEH: Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler

    private val unCaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler { thread, ex ->
        val stringWriter = StringWriter()
        ex?.printStackTrace(PrintWriter(stringWriter))
        val exception = stringWriter.toString()
        saveLogs(exception.toByteArray(), applicationContext)

        applicationContext.startActivity(Intent(Intent(applicationContext, ExceptionDisplay::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("error", exception)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        }))

        defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex)
        exitProcess(1)
    }


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        setupExceptionHandler()
    }


    private fun setupExceptionHandler() {
        try {
            defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()
            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(unCaughtExceptionHandler)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to get through this? I am also not able to launch an Activity from exception handler

Comment: unfortunately not