# How to properly write a custom UncaughtExceptionHandler in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

All I want to achieve is to catch exceptions on my app so that I can send them to a server. I figured out that I can do this by writing my custom **UncaughtExceptionHandler** base on native Android code in Java answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427515/using-global-exception-handling-on-android) in StackOverflow.

This is my **CustomExceptionHandler** class:

```
public class CustomExceptionHandler : Thread.IUncaughtExceptionHandler
{
    public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }

    public CustomExceptionHandler(Thread.IUncaughtExceptionHandler exceptionHandler)
    {
        Handle = exceptionHandler.Handle;
    }

    public void UncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
    {
        // Submit exception details to a server
        ...

        // Display error message for local debugging purposes
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then I used this class to set the **DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler** in my *Activity*:

```
// Set the default exception handler to a custom one
Thread.DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler = new CustomExceptionHandler(
    Thread.DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler);
```

I don't know what is wrong with this approach, it did build but I got an ***InvalidCastException*** on runtime.

[image: Error Image]

I have the same **Thread.IUncaughtExceptionHandler** interface types for my **CustomExceptionHandler** and the **DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler**, but why am I getting this error? Please enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: Try a `JavaCast<T>` here. https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Runtime.Extensions.JavaCast%7BTResult%7D/p/Android.Runtime.IJavaObject/

Comment: @JonDouglas I have used it.

Thread.DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler = Extensions.JavaCast<Thread.IUncaughtExceptionHandler>(
                new CustomExceptionHandler(Thread.DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler));

But still I get the same error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

And it strikes again :D This is a common mistake. You have to inherit `Java.Lang.Object` if you implement Java interfaces.

```cs
public class CustomExceptionHandler : Java.Lang.Object, Thread.IUncaughtExceptionHandler
{
    public void UncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
    {
        // Submit exception details to a server
        ...

        // Display error message for local debugging purposes
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely the answer to the problem. Thank you. :)