# Android not receiving PushNotification when App is "closed"

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I'm using GCM Service for push notification, it's working fine when App is open or in backgourd, but when app is closed it's Crashing:

[image]

Exception:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: br.com.siagri.SiagriAutorize, PID:
>   15786 android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable:
>   System.NotSupportedException: Could not activate JNI Handle 0xbeed8498
>   (key_handle 0xa7376b4) of Java type
>   'md5d8b390bb35897e87a51d1b4384dffa30/GcmService' as managed type
>   'SiagriAuth.Droid.Services.GcmService'. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init();
>   prior to using it.

I have followed this [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/data-and-cloud-services/google-messaging/google-cloud-messaging/) and taked a look at this [sample](https://github.com/Daniel-Krzyczkowski/MicrosoftAzure)
but i dont saw any about/diferent for notification works when the app is closed.

This is my method to recive and process the notification:

```
 private void CreateNotification(string title, string desc, string approvalCode)
        {
            try
            {
                //Create notification
                var notificationManager = GetSystemService(NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

                //Create an intent to show ui
                var uiIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

                //Use Notification Builder
                var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

                //Create the notification
                //we use the pending intent, passing our ui intent over which will get called
                //when the notification is tapped.
                var notification = builder.SetContentIntent(PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, 0))
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                        .SetTicker(title)
                        .SetContentTitle(title)
                        .SetContentText(desc)
                        .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High)
                        .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
                        //Set the notification sound
                        .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification))
                        //Auto cancel will remove the notification once the user touches it
                        .SetAutoCancel(true).Build();
                //Show the notification

                int uniqueIdentifier = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < approvalCode.Length; i++)
                {
                    uniqueIdentifier += (int)approvalCode[i];
                }
                notificationManager?.Notify(uniqueIdentifier, notification);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
                App.LocalAlert("Erro", "Erro ao criar notificação.");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            try
            {
                if (intent != null && intent.Extras != null)
                {
                    var messageText = intent.Extras.GetString("message");
                    var approvalCode = intent.Extras.GetString("ApprovalCode");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageText) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(approvalCode))
                        CreateNotification($"Solicitação - {approvalCode}", messageText, approvalCode);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
                App.LocalAlert("Erro", "Erro ao criar notificação.");
            }
        }
```

I'm using these assembly:

```
[assembly: Permission(Name = "myProject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "myProject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.INTERNET")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS")]
```

And these IntentFilter:

```
 [BroadcastReceiver(Permission = Constants.PERMISSION_GCM_INTENTS)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_MESSAGE }, Categories = new[] { "br.com.siagri.SiagriAutorize" })]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_REGISTRATION_CALLBACK }, Categories = new[] { "br.com.siagri.SiagriAutorize" })]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_LIBRARY_RETRY }, Categories = new[] { "br.com.siagri.SiagriAutorize" })]
```

Any idea of how to make this works for closed apps?

Obs.: I'm already running the app in release mode.

Comment: **`i'm gotting an error message`** And what is the error message?

Comment: hi @SushiHangover sory for saying that i got a erro message, the app is crashing. i provider a image.

Comment: Review the `logcat` for details of the crash and is it crashing during the local notification creation or when the use taps on the notification?

Comment: I don't know where it's crashing cause its closed so i cant debug, and when i run in debug mode, background and open, work fine. @SushiHangover

Comment: Review the `logcat` for details and/or implmenent a crash reporter

Comment: What is the `SIAGRI Autorize parou`? ANR? Please add [UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) to get the exception. If it is ANR, please use `adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt`  to get  the traces file, and edit your question.

Comment: @JoeLv SIAGRI Autorize is the name of my aplication, and "parou" is stop in portuguese.
I don't know how to get exception in this case cause when the application is close i cant debug.

Comment: Please try [`UnacughtExceptionHanlder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668236/how-to-properly-write-a-custom-uncaughtexceptionhandler-in-xamarin-android)

Comment: Visual Studio->tools->Android->Android Device Monitors, select your phone, you will see the log in console.

Comment: @JoeLv Thanks, i got the exception, i update the question

Comment: `You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it.`, Xamarin.Forms project?

Comment: Yes it is a Xamarin.Forms

Comment: [Have you seen this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593022/monodroid-error-when-calling-constructor-of-custom-view-twodscrollview/10603714#10603714)
 maybe you need adjust the code order

Comment: I don't, but i solve the problema, i was trying to access Database, instantiating my repository on GcmService constructor. Thank's @JoeLv u help me a lot.

Comment: I suggest you give an answer, so it will help other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My error was in the construct of GcmService, i was instantiating my repository there, so i was trying to access the database, i just remove from constructor and put on my registered method, that was where i used it.

```
 public GcmService() : base(PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver.SenderIds)
    {
        Log.Info(PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver.Tag, "PushHandlerService() constructor");
        _permissaoRepository = new PermissaoRepository(App.SiagriAuthContext);
        _loginRepository = new LoginRepository(App.SiagriAuthContext);
    }
```

I changed to:

```
public GcmService() : base(PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver.SenderIds)
    {
        Log.Info(PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver.Tag, "PushHandlerService() constructor");
    }
```

So i can't access my database when the app is closed, this is quite reasonable.
I have make a quick search of try to use database when app is closed but i dont found, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715613/use-a-local-database-in-xamarin) and [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/) have something about use local database.

Comment: saved me days. Thank you!