# App crashed and when clicked outside the crashed alert ,works good

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, crash

While launching the app I have requested permission and the request permission popup shows **but after the app crashed alert**. when i clicked OK button in the crashed popup it disappears and the app work's good

regards...

here is my code

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);
        Requestpermission();
    }

 private void Requestpermission()
    {

        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState) == Permission.Granted)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState }, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
```

**here is my image after app installed..........**

[image]

**after clicking Ok .........**

[image]

**LOG:**

Error   5368    AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10321 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getDeviceId(ITelephony.java:4426)
    at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(TelephonyManager.java:731)
    at md57d354519be1a75e7f096fe21d2760d3a.Login_Activity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at md57d354519be1a75e7f096fe21d2760d3a.Login_Activity.onCreate(Login_Activity.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)

Comment: It would be a good idea, to add any stack trace information that you were given, along with relevant snippets of code relating to where the error was being thrown within your solution. Otherwise we have no way to help you.

Comment: added my code..

Comment: Please add the logs.

Comment: i didn't got errors in my log

Comment: it says deploy succeeded...after that log is blank

Comment: Add [IUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668236/how-to-properly-write-a-custom-uncaughtexceptionhandler-in-xamarin-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to capture global exceptions. Or check if you have do something which spend too much time so that it block your UI thread. Or you can use [Diagnostic MSBuild Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting) to get more logs.

Comment: updated my post @JoeLv-MSFT

Comment: Have you added  `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in your manifest?

Comment: If your runtime permission request is right, try to delete bin and obj, restart VS.

Comment: already done that...still problem exists