# xamarin android app crashes when receiving notifications when app is in kill state

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I am using **FCM** for push notifications in xamarin forms mobile application.
When I receive notifications in android device when my app is in kill state(swiping the app to close), app gets crashed. But when app is in foreground/background it works well

I put some logs in *OnMessageReceived* method in firebase class. This code won't get executed and i have no idea why my app gets crashing when the notification status changed to success in server side.

Anyone having this same issue?

Comment: Please use [IUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39679199/8632294) to catch the exception.

Comment: Actually I'm using *UnhandledExceptionEventHandler* to catch the exception in **MainApplication**. For all the android crashes it helps me to know the crash. But for this crash this method not invoking.

Comment: Use adb command to get the log.