# Xamarin - Encoding Error 1252 data could not be found

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, encoding, visual-studio-2017

I am working on an application in `Xamarin` for `Visual Studio 2017`. I am attempting to test my application on `Android` and `iOS` live player devices. 
When I try to run it, I get the following error on my device (`Android` and `iOS`):

> Level=Error, Title=Visualization Error, Message=Encoding 1252 data
>   could not be found. Make sure you have correct international codeset
>   assembly installed and enabled. (NotSupportedException)

I have found similar issues through `Google` searching, but after making the changes, it still will not run. I have checked all Internationalization options for both devices, and I have even saved directly as `UTF-8` encoding, as I figured it may be an issue with encoding `windows-1252`. I also referenced the `I18N.dll` to the `I18N.West.dll` for both.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Update:**

I have been able to narrow down the issue further.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new 
 SqlConnection(Configuration.ConnectionString))
{
    //sqlConn.Open(); 
}
```

The `.open` was causing the encoding error. After commenting it out, the app will run on the live device, however, I now get:

> Level=Error, Title=Uncaught Exception, Message=Encoding 1252 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled. (NotSupportedException)

And `Visual Studio 2017` throws the following error

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

at

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new 
SqlConnection(Configuration.ConnectionString))
```

It occurs the moment it tries to pull from the database at the `using` statement above. I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2`. All I can tell is that it is having an issue with sending to and receiving from the SQL Server with `Android` and `iOS`.

**Update 2:**

After using some `Exception Handlers`, I boiled it down to this inner exception:

> {System.NotSupportedException: Encoding 1252 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled.
>     at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding (System.Int32 codepage) [0x0023f] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
>     at Mono.Data.Tds.TdsCharset.GetEncodingFromSortOrder (System.Int32 sortId) [0x00022] in :0 
>     at Mono.Data.Tds.TdsCharset.GetEncodingFromSortOrder (System.Byte[] collation) [0x00006] in :0 
>     at Mono.Data.Tds.TdsCharset.GetEncoding (System.Byte[] collation) [0x00008] in :0 
>     at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.ProcessEnvironmentChange () [0x00229] in :0 
>     at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.ProcessSubPacket () [0x00129] in :0 
>     at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.NextResult () [0x00039] in :0 
>     at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.SkipToEnd () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds70.Connect (Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionParameters connectionParameters) [0x0058e] in :0 
>     at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds80.Connect (Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionParameters connectionParameters) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open () [0x00245] in <868a6461786e4884ac572c5e90a6b7fd>:0 
>     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.QuietOpen (System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Data.ConnectionState& originalState) [0x0000c] in <868a6461786e4884ac572c5e90a6b7fd>:0 
>     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal (System.Data.DataSet dataset, System.Data.DataTable[] datatables, System.Int32 startRecord, System.Int32 maxRecords, System.String srcTable, System.Data.IDbCommand command, System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) [0x0002d] in <868a6461786e4884ac572c5e90a6b7fd>:0 
>     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill (System.Data.DataSet dataSet, System.Int32 startRecord, System.Int32 maxRecords, System.String srcTable, System.Data.IDbCommand command, System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) [0x00069] in <868a6461786e4884ac572c5e90a6b7fd>:0 
>     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill (System.Data.DataSet dataSet) [0x00029] in <868a6461786e4884ac572c5e90a6b7fd>:0 
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
>     at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 }

Which occurs at:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39679199/8632294) to add `IUncaughtExceptionHandler` for your app, and get the specific exception.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT As per your request, I used some exception handlers and that inner exception is my main issue.

Answer (score 32):

From the "iOS Build" Project Options page in Visual Studio for Mac you should check "west" checkbox. Same for Android properties.

[image]

In the the Android project, go to Properties -> Android Options

Then Linker Options, in the "Additional supported encodings" check "West".

Comment: You are lifesaver

Comment: For Visual Studio 2019 on Mac go to Project > ProjectName Tools Options -> Android Build -> Linker -> Internationalization -> Check the west box.

Comment: Shame that this hasn't been flagged as the accepted answer.

Comment: For Visual Studio for Mac 17.6 Preview: Right click on Android project -> Properties -> Android -> Linker -> scroll down to Internationalization section. I don't know why, but there are some missing so I had to edit csproj's attribute like this `<MandroidI18n>cjk;mideast;other;rare;west</MandroidI18n>`

Answer (score 12):

For VS2019, on windows : Check : 'Additional Supported Encodings'

[image]