# Xamarin, SQL, Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Broswer has been started

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, xamarin, mobile

This is my connection string:

```
private static string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-NAME\PRODUCTDB;User ID=USER;Password=********;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
SqlConnection connection;
```

This is my function:

```
public void checkForProduct(Int64 Scanned_EAN)
{
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Open the connection, so we can perform SQL commands
        connection.Open();                
    }
}
```

If I try to run this, I get the cannot connect to SQL Server browser. I have searched for 10 hours today and I can't seem to find the answer. The database is running, the server browser is running, I have let them through firewall, forwarded TCP, and UDP port for SQL. I am using SSMS, and I have managed to connect to the database using the server explorer in Visual Studio. But I can't connect via code.

Comment: It is a horrible, terrible, very bad idea to connect to your DB server directly from a mobile client.  Please don't do this.  But if you insist on doing it this way, it's unlikely your mobile device knows what "DESKTOP-NAME" is - use the IP instead.

Comment: I am aware of this, it's only for home use/fun/learning really.

Answer (score 0):

Try using IP address of your machine instead of "DESKTOP-NAME".

Comment: I tried doing: "Server = IP, por; Databse=...; User Id=...; Password= ...;" then I got TCP providor error: 40. Could not open connection to SQL server

Comment: And if i connect to the database via server explorer and then use that connection string, I get an error saying the connection string is invalid...

Answer (score 0):

I expend a couple days in order to fix it:

firstable you need to able the remote connections to your sql server instance:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UkHYNwUtCo

Therefore able the user sa in sql server:
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JFKUwT739Q

3. Finally solve the final bug related with the encode with this:
   [Xamarin - Encoding Error 1252 data could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586466/xamarin-encoding-error-1252-data-could-not-be-found)

Here is my connection string example:
connectionString = "Data Source=192.168.56.1,49170;Initial Catalog=Fundacion_feb2023;user id=sa;password=*****;";