# Encoding 1256 data could not be found

Tags: xamarin.android

Encoding 1256 data could not be found.  error when connect sql server
I am using visual studio 2019 for windows

```
Data Source=192.168.1.3,1433; User ID=asdf; Password=14132;
```

Comment: Possibly duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586466/xamarin-encoding-error-1252-data-could-not-be-found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin - Encoding Error 1252 data could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586466/xamarin-encoding-error-1252-data-could-not-be-found) (And before you mention it, it does not matter that the linked post uses 1252 and yours is about 1256.)