# catch all types of errors from whole application Android

Tags: android

I have a big Android application and I have a requirement to log all types of errors that could happen in my Application including `"Out of memory"` etc. 
Is it possible to accomplish?

I can use

```
try {

} catch(throwable t) {

}
```

but adding a whole code to `try/catch` sounds bad. And how can I catch an errors like "out of memory"?

Comment: If it is out-of-memory how does Android throws an Exception? ;)

Comment: I guess there is no way )

Comment: Actually my first comment is sarcasm. Btw all necessary Exceptions are defined in the Class/Methods therefore you know what to catch. And yeah using a generic exception e.g. `catch(Exception e)` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To tracking crash reports best way is using 3rd party libraries like Fabric or firebase(google). If you cannot use like this libraries, you can try this.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        if(ex.getClass().equals(OutOfMemoryError.class))
        {
            try {
                android.os.Debug.dumpHprofData(fileName);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simple replace `e.printStackTrace();` with `FirebaseCrash.report(e);` ie

Answer (score 1):

yes exactly it is possible. You can write a parent activity and handle exceptions globally like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427515/using-global-exception-handling-on-android). After that You can use [Google](http://www.google.com/analytics/?gclid=CPDijNyX39ECFQEL0wod1tYDiA) analytics, [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install) to view your daily reports of crashes etc

Comment: So I need to create a parent to each activity and it will catch all types of exceptions? Can I do it once in Application class for example?

Comment: possible in application class, or you need only one parent activity, all other activities in your app would be inherited from that parent or base activity.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to include analytics.

please refer [this](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics).
**crashlytics** is a library that can notify almost all problems. Try it.

Comment: Looks like a good way, but I can not use another libraries in my App.