# Catching an exception globally and changing activity

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have an app that consumes an API. With every request, I send a header with the version of my app, the server checks it, and if the version is too low, it would throw an error back. I did it like this so that if in the future I introduce breaking changes then I can show a nice message on the app instead of just crashing

Now any request throughout the app can potentially return this error, so what I want to do is catch this globally on every request and close whichever activity is open and open a new one saying some nice message like "Please go to play store to update your app".

Is it possible to do such thing?

To recap, i want to do 2 things:

1. From any request, generate an ObsoleteAppException through OkHttp/Retrofit
2. Capture only this exception globally, close any activity and open a new one with the warning

If its any useful, I am using RxJava2 and retrofit

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427515/using-global-exception-handling-on-android

Comment: I just edited my text, cause this is not exactly what i want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` in your `Application` class to catch all exceptions in your app and check if the app should crash or show an update message.

This article [Hide your crashes gracefully (and still report them)](https://proandroiddev.com/hide-your-crashes-gracefully-and-still-report-them-9b1c85b25875) and many other [libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/21?sort=rating) can help you "Catch exception globally in Android".

As for changing current activity, there are already answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13994622/5507158). It basiclly tracks every activity. When you need to change current activity, just finish current one and start a new one.

This whole approach seems like a bit of overkill for your case but I don't have a better idea...Maybe a custom RxJava exception handler to catch this exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UCE Handler](https://github.com/jampez77/UCE-Handler) to catch exceptions and present the user with options on how to handle it.

In your Project's build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

In your Application's or Module's build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.jampez77:UCE-Handler:uce_handler:1.4.1'
}
```

In your Application class initialize library using builder pattern:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override 
    public void onCreate() { 
        ...
        // Initialize UCE_Handler Library
        new UCEHandler.Builder(this).build();
    }
}
```

Then make sure you update you manifest as follows:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
```