# Logging on Android phones

Tags: android, debugging, logging

call it crazy, but I never use debugging, just logging when developing software for mobile phones... So when coming from Symbian to Android platform I was looking for something similar here. After searching for a while I figured out a way of using logs (I need live logs during the devlopment and file with logs, when testers are using the application), and I would like to ask the audience to comment and might be make an interesting suggestions:

- I am using the **Log** class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)
- I am using the **adb logcat** to see the live output from emulator or USB connected device
- Since I am developing on Windows I am using the GNU **grep** port to filter data out from  **adb logcat**, which do not belong to my application (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)
- If I need logs from testers I ask them to use the **Log collector** application to send logs over Bluetooth to the PC (http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/)

I welcome any comments to my approach...

BR

STeN

Comment: There is no need to use grep as logcat supports filtering. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.htmladb ( IE: logcat MyApp:D )

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments you need not use grep , logcat supports filtering.

I have never used the log-collector but what I prefer is to write all logs to the SD card and also have an UncaughtExceptionHandler which logs to separate files . Only a few lines of code are 
required and it can entirely be controlled by a configuration parameter.

Edit : UEH sample : [How do I obtain crash-data from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application/755151#755151)

Comment: Hi, can you paste here an UncaughtExceptionHandler example? Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be, you can add java.util.logger in your code. Instead of Log.v, use java.util.logger functionality. This is a powerful logger, which can help you publish the log on to a log file on the sdcard and logcat, both at the same time. You can check this link:-

[How to configure java.util.logging.logger in android to use a logging properties file placed on the sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880756/how-to-configure-java-util-logging-logger-in-android-to-use-a-logging-properties/10880805#10880805)