# Catch a crash-n-reboot of an Android device

Tags: android, debugging, service, crash

I'm writing an application. It has a Service which is started using a receiver of `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`.

One of my app's users is reporting a strange problem (by the way, he is using LG Optimus One device with original 2.2 firmware) - after some interactions with my app (adding some data to a database which is used somehow by a Service) and after that resetting a device (hardware off and then on) device is going to infinite reboot just after 10 second after start.

I think this crash-n-restart is related to my app or it's service ('cause there is not such crash after hard-reset and using a phone without my app).

The question is.

1. Is there any known bugs with LG Optimus One related to on-boot-starting a crashing service?
2. How can i catch this bug? Is `adb logcat` is suitable here (is logcat is accessible right after the phone is powered on, when the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast is sent?)
3. I there any other debug techniques which i can use in my case?

Comment: So can you recreate this locally, or are you talking about debugging it with a remote user / through the android market stack dump interface?

Comment: I can recreate it locally. I just can build some special version with extensive debugging and send it directly to user having this crash. He can't send me a dump through a market cause' his phone is totally unusable, going to reboot just after the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Don't know

2) Could you do this, works in an Activity not sure about service:

```
public void onCreate(){
 Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(onBlooey);
}

private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler onBlooey = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "MAINPAGE Thread Uncaught exception", ex);
                    // Do what ever you want maybe send this exception to a dump file on the SD

            }
    };
```

3) The above

There is also this project on *Remotely log unhandled exceptions in your Android applications.*: http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/

*EDIT*

This answer could be helpful to you: [How do I obtain crash-data from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application)

Comment: Thank you, this is great feature. I'll try and tell you results.