# Android How to Debug on PowerUp?

Tags: android

I am getting exceptions on device Powerup. My app starts on receiving boot intent.  I would welcome any and all suggestions about how to debug on Powerup?  When I just powerup the debugger is not attached by default.  I am on sdk 2.1 and eclipse using adb debugger.  Thanks.

Also if the debugger does not attach where exactly would I find the error message from the crash on the device?  Which log file?  Where exactly should I look for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/601503/329637). There it is explained how you can set a DefaultExceptionHandler that catches all uncatched exceptions in your application and then writes it to a file or send it to a server.

In your case, both solution are applicable.. If you write it to a file you can check this file after booting. If you send it to a server or email you the you just have to assure that the exception handler waits until network connection is available.

Comment: Thanks.  I see a few good options there.  Any comments on which one has worked for you?

Comment: I myself used the solution proposed by me and I also wrote my own handler as described in the topvoted answer.

Comment: TimestampFormatter is from which library?

Comment: I did not find timestamp formatter.  Are there other choices for getting timestamp as string.  Thanks

Comment: Never mind about timestamp.  How should this be applied where there is local service?  Will it catch those as well?

Comment: If another worker thread is spun off does one need to set handler for that thread as well?  Thanks

Comment: Most importantly how from CustomerErrorHandler can we request to goto a particular activity like error handling activity.  This is like to going to error web page.  How can one use this to get there?  Thanks.

Comment: Please comment on my next post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740843/android-global-error-handling-and-reporting-activity