# Bug reporting tool / library for developing applications

Tags: android, bug-tracking

Is there a way to report Bugs, similar to the Android Feedback Client, but without registering my application at the market. I'm still working on the application and some users are alpha testing it so it would be useful to receive reports/ stacktraces etc. Is there a common way or an application for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look at ACRA Project - http://acra.googlecode.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Instabug](https://instabug.com) which lets you report bugs right from the app by shaking the phone. It sends you all the device details, network logs, view hierarchy inspection,  as well as the steps to reproduce it. It takes a line of code to integrate.

---

For full disclosure. I work at Instabug.

Answer (score 1):

I've used acra and it works well: http://acra.googlecode.com/

see: [How do I obtain crash-data from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Android Remote Stacktrace](http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/) before, it was very easy to setup, but when I set it up I don't think it had as many options as [A.C.R.A](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) does - I haven't used either in a while so I'm not sure which is better.