# Gson library and Proguard

Tags: android, json, gson, proguard

I have got an issue with proguard and the Gson library. My code is

```
AdServerResult result = (AdServerResult) new Gson().fromJson(json, 
      AdServerResult.class);
```

*(I create a new `AdServerResult` object using the Gson library)*

My `AdServerResult` class :

```
public class AdServerResult {

    public ArrayList<AdServerObject> shorts ;
    public ArrayList<AdServerObject> longs ;

    public ArrayList<AdServerObject> getShorts() {
        return shorts;
    }
    public void setShorts(ArrayList<AdServerObject> shorts) {
        this.shorts = shorts;
    }
    public ArrayList<AdServerObject> getLongs() {
        return longs;
    }
    public void setLongs(ArrayList<AdServerObject> longs) {
        this.longs = longs;
    }

    //for debug
    @Override
    public String toString(){

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;

        if (shorts!=null && shorts.size()>0){
            for (AdServerObject s: shorts){
                sb.append("url: "+s.getPicture_url());
            }
        }

        if (longs!=null && longs.size()>0){
            for (AdServerObject s: longs){
                sb.append("url: "+s.getPicture_url());
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

My `AdServerObject` (present in the `AdServerResult` class) :

```
public class AdServerObject{

    public String appli_id;
    public String picture_url;

    public String getAppli_id() {
        return appli_id;
    }
    public void setAppli_id(String appli_id) {
        this.appli_id = appli_id;
    }
    public String getPicture_url() {
        return picture_url;
    }
    public void setPicture_url(String picture_url) {
        this.picture_url = picture_url;
    }       
}
```

And my "json" string is as below :

```
{ 
  "shorts": [
    { "appli_id": "282", "picture_url": "xxxx"},
    { "appli_id": "275", "picture_url": "xxx" }
  ], 
  "longs": [
    {"appli_id": "MyAppli3", "picture_url": "xxxxx"},
    {"appli_id": "MyAppli4", "picture_url": "xxxxx" }
  ]

}
```

This code works but when exporting with proguard, the `AdServerResult` instance is `null`.

My proguard file (only the json part) :

```
# for gson (GSON @Expose annotation)
-keep public class com.google.gson.Gson
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

...

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*

...

-keep public class jp.xxx.ad_server.AdServerResult
-keep public class jp.xxx.ad_server.AdServerObject
-keepclassmembers class jp.xxx.ad_server.AdServerObject
-keepclassmembers class jp.xxx.ad_server.AdServerResult
```

I have used this `Gson().fromJson` many times but I never encountered a such problem.... I am struggling with this issue for 12 hours and my brain is about to explode.

--
EDIT

I have updated proguard(4.11) but problem remains.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533676/proguard-and-gson-on-android-classcastexception?rq=1  the top answer might help

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My proguard file is similar to the " proguard configuration for Gson" of https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to keep the fields of the classes that you are serializing, with their original names:

```
-keepclassmembers class jp.xxx.ad_server.AdServerResult$AdServerObject { <fields>; }
-keepclassmembers class jp.xxx.ad_server.AdServerResult { <fields>; }
```

ProGuard may otherwise rename or even remove them.

Comment: Thank you Eric for your help (2nd time in few months ) and also for this awesome tool ! cheers

Comment: I am getting a lot of issues with Gson while using proguard, how can i keep gson from