# DatabaseException: Firebase crashes only on signed APK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app works fine on the simulator and on my physical device when I run via Android Studio, but it immediately crashes when I use a signed APK (or install it from Play Store). I used Android Studio's Firebase Assistant to setup everything.

Here's my onCreate:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

        final Activity context = this;
        // Read from the database
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                GenericTypeIndicator<List<University>> genericTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<University>>() {};
                colleges = dataSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator);

                List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (University college : colleges){
                    names.add(college.name);
                }

                if (colleges.size() > 0) {
                    CustomList customList = new CustomList(context, colleges, names);
                    listView.setAdapter(customList);
                    setListeners();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is exception that you are getting? You could share stacktrace.

Comment: @JakubSzczygieł com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException

Comment: Mohammed, yes but stack trace would be useful.

Comment: If Proguard  is set to obfuscate your files, (`minifyEnabled=true`), this may be the problem.  If so, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533676/proguard-and-gson-on-android-classcastexception?rq=1).  It's a different exception but it may help.

Comment: @JakubSzczygieł unfortunately, I couldn't get any more information because it doesn't crash when running via Android Studio. I got this from Google Play Console.

Comment: Ok, so what was the message associated with this DatabaseException if any?

Comment: @Gary99 I have `minifyEnabled = false`, and setting it to false results in `Execution failed for task: app:tranformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease.`

Comment: @JakubSzczygieł I could get this report from my users:  `at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:0)
  at com.geekMohammad.itotal.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:72)` ~ It crashes at onDataChange

Comment: You can upload your proguard mapping to Google play console to get the full stacktrace

Comment: Well unless you upload proguard mapping to play console as @cricket_007 mentioned, you can use fabric.io or other crash tool that will gather more information about crashes (and again with mapping) will allow you to figure out what is wrong.