# Uncaught exception within uncaught exception handler

Tags: java, exception, uncaught-exception

This question may sound a little silly ;)

How would approach the possibility of an uncaught exception within the [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)?

Comment: Does it mean that you have on UncaughtExceptionHandler and now you want to handle Uncaught exceptions within that handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have to catch them yourself. The documentation of `uncaughtException()` linked by you states this clearly:

> Any exception thrown by this method will be ignored by the Java Virtual Machine.

But you can only plan so far. So you handle the exceptions of your exception handler but who handles that code? It's the same with logging a failed logging event. Exception handlers all the way down...

Comment: Hmm that's strange. When i tested it on Android it seemed to loop when i threw an exception on purpose. Guess it's some kind of Android bug.

Comment: It looped for me too when I introduced a bug, er I mean "tested" it on, I believe, IBM AIX.

Comment: @mibollma, Is Android a standard JVM?

Comment: @Pacerier I don't think it's going through the Java standardization process. However in this case it's more likely that it was a bug as the android documentation states almost the same behaviour: http://d.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html#uncaughtException%28java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable%29

Comment: @mibollma, Weird, I'm getting the same behavior on "normal" JVMs: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24834702/632951

Answer (score 5):

Very interesting question, I haven't thought about this before.

The approch seems to be that either set your own `uncaughtExceptionHandler` on your thread or it will get passed to JAVAs `defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`,

I made some quick googeling and found a similar case for getting crash data from android.
I think you may be intresing in this link [How do I obtain crash-data from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application)

Comment: The question was more like what happens if you try to shutdown a component in case of an uncaught exception inside the uncaught exception handler and that component throws an exception too.