# Do errors thrown within UncaughtExceptionHandler get swallowed?

Tags: java, exception, jvm, uncaught-exception, uncaughtexceptionhandler

[`Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html#uncaughtException(java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable)) states that when the method which handles uncaught exceptions itself throws an exception, that exception will be ignored:

> void **uncaughtException**(Thread t, Throwable e):
>
> Method invoked when the given thread terminates due to the given
>   uncaught exception.
>
> **Any exception thrown by this method will be ignored by the Java
>   Virtual Machine.**

However when I tested it, the JVM did not ignore the exceptions handled by the uncaught exception handler`:

```
public static void main(final String args[]) {
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread arg0, Throwable arg1) {
            throw new java.lang.RuntimeException("e2");
        }
    });
    throw new RuntimeException("e1");
}
```

Eclipse Console output (JRE 1.7):

> Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException thrown from the
>   UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"

Another oddity I found out is that the output I get isn't coming from `System.err`. It seems to be from another stream altogether. I verified this by redirecting `System.err` to `System.out`, but I'm still getting "red" output:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.setErr(System.out);
    System.out.println(System.err == System.out);
    System.err.println("this is black color");
    try {
        throw new Error("test stacktrace color");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("from handler");
        }
    });
    throw new RuntimeException("from main");
}
```

The output (bolded signifies red color):

> true
>
> this is black color
>
> java.lang.Error: test stacktrace color at asf.df.main(df.java:13)
>
> **Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"**

What's the explanation for these phenomenons?

What happens to errors thrown within UncaughtExceptionHandler? What's the expected (documented or guaranteed) behavior?

Comment: Possibly version specific?

Comment: Even in the previous Java versions, the docs state that it should be ignored by the JVM.

Comment: In Oracle "1.6.0_39" / Ubuntu 12.04, the exception thrown from within the uncaught exception handler is swallowed by the JVM. Like @Andrew_CS said, it could be version/vendor specific.

Comment: Define "did not ignore". It probably prints a stack trace but doesn't exit the thread that calls these methods, in the same way that the Swing event thread catches, prints, and ignores RTEs rather than exiting.

Comment: @EJP, "ignore" is the keyword used by the docs. They didn't define it, but from the output I'm getting, it's likely "not ignored".

Comment: Perhaps Eclipse is trying to be "helpful"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HotSpot JVM prints the exceptions thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler.
See [JavaThread::exit](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/c55d012dd067/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.cpp#l1799)

```
    if (HAS_PENDING_EXCEPTION) {
      ResourceMark rm(this);
      jio_fprintf(defaultStream::error_stream(),
            "\nException: %s thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler"
            " in thread \"%s\"\n",
            pending_exception()->klass()->external_name(),
            get_thread_name());
      CLEAR_PENDING_EXCEPTION;
    }
```

JVM prints these exceptions itself directly on `stderr` regardless of the `System.err` state - whether it was redirected or not.

Well, this kind of warning does not affect the application - in this sense the exception is "ignored". But you are right, this behavior is not obvious. Javadoc is misleading and is better to be fixed.

Comment: +1, But isn't it the other way round, that HotSpot should be fixed to adhere to the JLS?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to ignore exceptions silently. Such cases would be hard to debug. BTW, this is just an API documentation which is not a part of JLS or JVMS. Javadoc tends to become obsolete as the implementation changes - this happens rather often due to performance optimizations, new features etc. For instance, the default `hashCode` is said to be usually implemented by converting an internal object address, but this is not true for HotSpot JVM.

Answer (score 2):

The exceptions are ignored and processing continues when thrown from a non-main thread.

If it is thrown in main the error code returned is non-zero.

The unhandled exceptions are logged via syserr.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread()
                .setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void uncaughtException(final Thread t, final Throwable e) {

                        System.out.println("In child UncaughtExceptionHandler at " + java.time.Instant.now());

                        throw new RuntimeException("From child thread UncaughtExceptionHandler"
                                + java.time.Instant.now());

                    }
                });
            throw new RuntimeException("from runnable");
        }
    });

    Thread.currentThread()
    .setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(final Thread t, final Throwable e) {

                System.out.println("In main UncaughtExceptionHandler " + java.time.Instant.now());

                throw new RuntimeException("From main thread UncaughtExceptionHandler" + java.time.Instant.now());

        }
    });

    myThread.start();

    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(2));

    System.out.println("After child thread: " + java.time.Instant.now());

    //Will result in a non-zero return code
    throw new RuntimeException("from main");
}
```

**Output:**

In child UncaughtExceptionHandler at 2014-07-19T04:10:46.184Z

Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-0"
After child thread: 2014-07-19T04:10:48.197Z
In main UncaughtExceptionHandler 2014-07-19T04:10:48.197Z

Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"

Comment: From your output, we see "Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread Thread-0". If so, why do you say that the exception is ignored when thrown from a non-main thread?

Comment: It writes to syserr but exceptions thrown in non-main thread handlers are not propagated and do not modify the return code on exit. From an execution stand point they are ignored.

Comment: **1)** It does not write to system.error. I tried this by redirecting System.err to System.out (see the second code snippet in the question), but the output is still red color. **2)** And also, obviously exceptions thrown in different threads do not propagate to each other, regardless of whether we used UncaughtExceptionHandler or not....

Comment: If it's red in Eclipse's console, unless the defaults have changed, it's standard error. Also verified running outside Eclipse and piping to standard error. I think once an exception is thrown from main System stream redirects (out,err) are lost.

Comment: No, (look at the code in the question) I've already redirected System.err to System.out, so System.err.println will print black not red. If it's red, it indicates that it's *another* stream, not System.err any longer.

Comment: It appears those messages are being emitted directly from the JVM to standard error, it does not appear that manipulating System streams can change this behavior.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying... (The question is thus:) Are these weird behaviors documented? What's the specification then, and Can we rely on them?

Comment: @apangin beat me to the source.