# Immediate force close on launch

Tags: java, android, error-handling

I've had a report from one user of my app that it force-closes upon launching.
This is the only report out of all of my users of this happening, which leads me to believe that it is a problem that comes with his firmware.

His device is a HTC Desire HD running the latest Cyanogenmod Nightly ROM, and the (only) error produced in the logcat was:

> W/dalvikvm( 3013): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x40015560)

has anyone any ideas as to what is going wrong with my app on his device?

**EDIT:**
Problem actually turned out to be an unhandled null exception from a UUID in onCreate()

Comment: The reason you're getting downvoted is that there is no possible way for anyone here to answer this question on a technical level. That being said, the answer is "Your single user with a problem has a horked up ROM and you don't need to worry about it"

Comment: I see, at the moment, I'm not any good with reading errors, and I thought that those codes within the error related to a specific part of my app, which is why I posted. And I appreciate that I shouldn't be bending over backwards for a single user, but my app has quite a lot of users now, but the only ones that seem to be rating it are the few which experience problems, which is affecting my overall rating (for example, the guy who reported this f/c, rated 1 star, causing overall rating to drop to 3.5)

Answer (score 2):

First, don't bang your head over one user with custom nightly ROM.

Second, I HIGHLY recommend you add [default exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application) to catch all unhandled exceptions and upload them to your server. I set my code so that they are uploaded directly to issue tracking system.