# Android - ProGuard modification causes the app to crash

Tags: android, stack-trace, proguard

My app works fine when it's unsigned (debugging, etc..), also when exporting without ProGuard.
But when I export it with ProGuard, When a piece of code containing native methods that I import is executing, it crashes.

What can I do? I guess that getting the stack trace, but I have no idea how to do that...

I have tried this: [How do I obtain crash-data from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application) But no files actually appear where they should (I guess I have done that wrong too :()

The device MUST be saving crash stack traces SOMEWHERE. Where are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proguard.cfg in your project has a collection of ignore rules for classes that shouldn't be obfuscated. You can essentially ignore everything and slowly obfuscate code each pass. Native methods, methods called by reflection-indirection shouldn't be obfuscated.

Comment: Thanks :) I have found that on my own a few hours ago but your post did summarize it for the following readers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Fragment class add the following line to your proguard.cfg file:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
```