# Android Developer Console Stacktrace

Tags: android, google-play, stack-trace

I have an App available in the Android Market.
From time to time i get error reports in the Developer Console. For about 6 month there have been no more stack-traces visible. At first I though no more post-froyo bugs: 'yay'!
Recently I did some testing using a droid 2 which I am sure is not pre-froyo, I ran into an error, reported it, and never received this report in the Console.

Did I miss some configuration or option that enables me to receive stacktraces?
Is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why you don't receive stack traces anymore nor how could you enable them. I have always felt Android Market is a somewhat unreliable service: reports are not accurate, downloads/active counts randomly change at times, crash reports not received, and so on.

However, I have *suggestions* how to implement similar functionality yourself and with a more reliable fashion: [How do I obtain crash-data from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application)

Basically there are two options:

1. Use an *existing* component (like [acra](http://code.google.com/p/acra/))
2. *DIY* by catching all uncaught exceptions.

(So you would have an option should you fail to receive a real solution)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to stop listening to android market and work with other tools.

You should consider using a crash report tool like http://www.bugsense.com/ which is simple effective and meaningful

NOTE: i am not linked nor affiliated in any way with bugsense owners. I am just a simple user.