# How to react on a force close?

Tags: android, forceclose

I'm developing a first app for android, and I sometimes get a message "this application stopped unexpectedly" and a "close" button.

- How can I find out what's wrong? When the phone is connected to the computer, it would show in the Logcat of Eclipse, but my phone is not always connected to my computer. How do you handle that? How do you handle the error reporting in your app when it's not in debuggable status?
- How can I configure my app to restart in such an occasion? I have an other app (not developped by me) which sometimes shows the message that it restarted after memory low (or something like that). I'd like to restart my app too when, for whatever reason, it crashed.

Anybody?

Comment: Logcat info is saved even if your phone is not connected to a computer.  When you connect it later, you can retrieve the logcat and view the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your device is not connected to a computer, you can see the logcat output using the following app: [aLogcat](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat)

Also, I'm not sure that restarting an app that has just crashed is a good idea. This could lead to an infinite loop of crashing/restarting.

Comment: can I somehow have the app send me this information, if it happens on somebody elses phone?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the second question but for the first part you can run adb logcat in background. for that just go to the folder location where adb.exe esixts, in command prompt and just type

> adb logcat > /data/log.txt &

it will run in the background and store the logs in log.txt file. When you are done with your force close. just type following command

> adb pull /data/log.txt .

it will extract the logs, and will put in the current directory location, you can open it using any text editor.