# Is there a file which contains all crash report in andorid device

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports

As my title, i need to know whether a file contains all the crash report in android. Let me explain in detail. In iphone developer can take all crash reports in iphone application by synchronizing the device into system in the specific directory in Mac.All the crash reports are stored in directory with the individual device name.

Likewise i need to get all the crash report for android device. As i googled, i got some suggestion as using ACRA we can get the crash report in Google Doc or as email.

Is there a single way to get crash report or any other way to get it? If so please guide to get the crash report. i'm in running out of time.

Comment: first read all the things mentioned in ACRA project. Everything is given there which you want. Its mentioned about writing on text file to store it into sdcard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the rrainn answer here [Get crash data (stack traces at least) from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application)

You can get the crash report at any particular location you desired on SD card, you can send to server as well if you need

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same issue as well on a Galaxy Note S2 running Jellybean 4.1.2.  My Gingerbread and ICS test devices work fine.  I also saw this post indicating that issue is related to some CSS handling bugs in Webkit in some versions:

http://css-tricks.com/crashing-mobile-webkit/

In my case adding a single input control or button is enough to reliably trigger the issue.

Your post and links have been very helpful.  I'm going to see if I can't strip down my CSS to mitigate the bug.