# Android app crash report

Tags: java, android

I want to send the detailed log in background when the application crash. How can I implement this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use remote stack trace to get crash report when your application force close.

Source code available [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/).

Answer (score 2):

I've used http://www.bugsense.com for several projects and it's great! It can also send you an email when new errors are sent to it.

BugSense also works with ACRA: http://www.bugsense.com/features/acra

If you want to do it yourself, you'll need to look into setting your own uncaught exception handler and then try and do the sending part (by email or to a website): https://stackoverflow.com/a/755151/349012

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve is already done by ACRA, By using ACRA we can get creah reports [ACRA–Easy Crash Log Reporting for Android](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)

Comment: You'll need an uncaught exception handler. Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/755151/349012

Answer (score 0):

You can use ACRA to get the crash report. Check this link out http://code.google.com/p/acra/

Answer (score 0):

If you want exception log, first get the exception in catch block and store it in to some variable and send this to your server using `HTTP POST` or `GET` method, if you want you can save it in to your database on server side.