# How to send crash reports to developer?

Tags: android, crash-reports, forceclose

I develop android app but in some cases my app `force close`

How can I send email to developer contains details if `force close` happen in any time ?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to send the stacktrace to you, because you are the developer, are you looking for a remote stacktrace?

Comment: The [ACRA library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/601503/87698) puts crash reports into a Google spreadsheet. Maybe that's a viable alternative to an e-mail?

Comment: A.S. yes I want to send trace to my email

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) library will fulfill your requirement. You just need to setup the email. The tutorial and setup is defined [here.](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#sending-reports-by-email)

Download the library with .jar in lib

You just need to define the Application class and write the following code just above application class  and override `onCreate()` method like this

```
     @ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", // will not be used
                    mailTo = "reports@yourdomain.com",
                    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
                    resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
    public class MyApplication extends Application {

 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        ACRA.init(this);
        super.onCreate();
    }

}
```

Thats it. The email action will get opened whose body contains crash report.

Comment: Arca's the best!  Also, I would add, that you don't need to download the jars.  You can also just add:  compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.2' (find newest) to your gradle build dependencies as well, if using gradle.

Answer (score 3):

You can Use ready APi Such as [BugSence](https://www.bugsense.com/) and [crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/)

After implementation SDK you will recive crush report 
with crush logs to your email if you whant

For BugSance 
Download SDK

```
import com.bugsense.trace.BugSenseHandler;
```

Make sure you also add the line

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to your app's AndroidManifest.xml file. BugSense uses this permission to send the crash reports and performance metrics.

add the BugSenseHandler in your activity before setContentView. Then you are ready to go!

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(Context, APIKEY);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //rest of your code here
  }
```

The InitAndStartSession method installs the BugSense exception handler and the performance monitor. It then sends all the previously saved crash reports and performance metrics. At the same time, it starts a new session for your activity.

Here's an example on how to use the InitAndStartSession:

```
BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(MyActivity.this, "YOURAPIKEY");
```

Whenever you want to explicitly start the session, you can use the startSession method at the onStart method of your activity, as follows:

```
BugSenseHandler.startSession(MyActivity.this);
```

Whenever you want to close the session, you can use the closeSession method as follows:

```
BugSenseHandler.closeSession(MyActivity.this);
```

Close session will close the current session, offering better tracking of the sessions for your users.

If you want to manually flush all the saved data, use the BugSenseHandler.flush(Context) method:

```
BugSenseHandler.flush(MyActivity.this);
```

More Documentation [Android BugSence Doc](https://www.bugsense.com/docs/android)