# Metaio Android SDK: crash on Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: android, android-ndk, 64-bit, augmented-reality, metaio

I have an application that uses the Metaio SDK to show some Augmented Reality stuff.

I have an issue where the app crashes when running it on Samsung Galaxy S6. Unfortunately I don't have any logcat logs for the issue.

I found this link http://helpdesk.metaio.com/questions/46459/android-sdk-arm64-support/46479.html talking about a similar issue, it relates to the 64-bit CPU on the Samsung S6, but I'm not sure if this is the cause of my issue.

Has anyboday seen something similar to this before?

Comment: If you don't have physical access to the device, but you want to receive the crash dump, you can use [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) (requires rebuild of your app, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22473552/192373), or Power Menu Bug Report (requires configuring Developer Options on the client device).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question and Metaio is not there anymore, but the solution was to upgrade the Metaio SDK to the latest availble version back then.

Answer (score 0):

it has good chances to be related to your issue.

When you install an APK on Android, the system will look for native libraries directories (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64, mips64, mips) inside the `lib` folder of the APK, in the order determined by `Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS`.

If your app happen to have an `arm64-v8a` directory with other libs, the 32-bit metaio libs will not be installed as the libs aren't mixed. That means you have to provide the full set of your libraries for each architecture.

So, to solve your issue, you can remove your 64-bit libs from your build, or set abiFilters to package only 32-bit architectures:

```
android {
    ....
    defaultConfig {
        ....
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
    }
}
```

If you get an error related to the use of the deprecated NDK support, add `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` to a file named *gradle.properties* at the root of your project. Don't feel bad about using a deprecated integration, as using *abiFilters* is still the cleanest way atm to filter out 64-bit libs from an APK.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already removed other arm64 libs and it still not working, I'll go for the deprecated NDK approach, but I'm using eclipse without gradle, where to set this configuration?