# How to save Logging on Android to file and send it to server?

Tags: android, logging

I would like to catch Exceptions and also track how the program runs, also interaction of user...
Can anyone give me some directions?

I need to implement Logging in my Application.

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following:

Google Analytics for Android:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/

Crittercism for bug tracking like you are describing:
http://www.crittercism.com/

There are other bug tracking platforms but I only have experience with Crittercism.