# How to trap/send error message to email when mobile app crash?

Tags: android, error-handling, runtime-error

I am looking for possible ways on how to trap or catch the run time errors of my application. I want to send my apk to my friends for them to test but when the application gets a run time error, I could not get the error message.

Ive already look in the net and I found some code set up but If there is already an available library for this, it would be very helpful.

Thanks guys

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application

Comment: Thanks @Giru Bhai for quick response. I'll check it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a helpful library called ACRA(Application Crash Report for Android). https://github.com/ACRA/acra .It will send an email or crash report and its really easy to set up.

Thanks @Giru Bhai for the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2855736/3150510)