# Extract stack info from stripped libraries in Android Native Application

Tags: android, android-ndk, stack-trace, stripping

Generally, all native libraries built for release version are stripped that are used in Android Application. Suppose we now get a crash from an App downloaded from Playstore and we get the backtrace from log cat using adb. Running ndk stack using the stripped library will not give us the file number and name info since symbol tables are missing. Is there any alternative to get the correct backtrace even if the library is stripped and built for release version?

I knw there are couple of options provide at [How do I obtain crash-data from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application) , but my question is more towards getting stack trace from stripped libraries. I might not be surprised if there are no alternatives since symbol table is must to get correct stack trace. Any Pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent libraries mean absent references. Your only option is to ship your app with the libraries you suspect to be the cause of the problem and see if you can trace it from there. Good luck.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. The library is there and is integrated into apk. But how to stack trace using adb log cat if the libraries are stripped? For more info, here is the detail https://gitorious.org/mingw-android-ndk/mingw-android-ndk/source/189c83350c6a52225e263fa51d6154e4f04040ea:docs/NDK-STACK.html

Comment: an integrated library should be included in your APK. As you said, native libraries are "stripped" meaning that they are not present...

Comment: by stripped, I mean running file <library> on linux and verify the library is stripped(i.e. stripped off debug symbols)