# Exported (Uploaded) apk to the Play store getting crashed

Tags: android

I have published an app on the play store yesterday. Now the app is live but when I tried to install the app from the Play store, its not even showing the splash screen. It's just show unfortunately stopped Error. the .apk from the project is working fine.

How do I fix this?

I have used the following as reference to upload the apk on the play store

http://www.instructables.com/id/Publishing-an-Android-App-to-the-Google-Play-Store/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: Install the same apk on your phone and print crash logs here.

Comment: the apk is working fine. and not working when exported to play store.

Comment: you can check the crash log from the google play developer console.. examine than, if you have no clue post that here

Comment: @user3705697 install the same signed apk on your phone by adb command. I mean the same apk which you uploaded on playstore. There cant be a case where it works fine when you install via adb, and crash via playstore.

Comment: @StinePike there is no crash report in crash log on the google play developer console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the apk file that you uploaded to play store.Do install the same and check the crashlog .I am sure the issue will be with the apk so you need to upload new.

**Do clean the project and export your signed apk.**

And also for checking the crash log for remote devices you need to add library like ACRA do check the SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application)
[How do I obtain crash-data from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application)

Comment: thank you. I have fixed the apk by cleaning the project again and re-exporting the apk.

Answer (score 3):

Clean your code and publish the signed apk again, it happened with me twice.

**EDIT:**
Removing warnings will be a plus point, Clean your project, make signed app and before deploying run this apk in to your phone for testing.

Answer (score 3):

When you sign apk some times if it is not properly signed then references are mismatched and exception will occur for casting views.So every time clean your project and directly export your apk without run the code.After exporting apk test in your device before uploading on play store to check weather it is running properly or not.