# Best open source crash reporting tool for Android Application

Tags: android, crash-reports

I want to use crash reporting tool for my application but i don't have budget. Can any one have idea of any open source crash reporting tool except crashlytics.

Comment: Is there any tools availabe which i can use in my application and publish in playstore.

Comment: If you are gonna upload your appliocation on playstore then why are you adding any crash reporting tool. Yow can get your crash reports on developer console.

Comment: more detailed answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best one is [Splunk Api](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MintAndroidSDK).Download the **splunk-mint.jar** and place it in your `libs` folder.The just added the following code before `setContentView()` within `onCreate()`:

```
Mint.initAndStartSession(MainActivity.this, "Your api key");
```

You will able to see the entire log-cat/crash report in the splunk website.

Comment: I have to use this code in all the component available in my app or only in activity.

Comment: In your activity,where you suspect that an eror can occur.