# if my app crashes, when I reopen the app, how to know the app just crashed?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I tried to look at crashlytics but did not find any solution, could there be an intent maybe?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679624/detect-app-crash-in-android

Comment: i think you want to read logs locally. With crashlytic its not possible i think . [have a look at this anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69339885/force-firebasecrashlytics-print-logs-to-console/69340289#69340289) . Services works in different ways for instance `Acra` used to open a mail intent with crash report in old days haven't used it from long time . can u add some explaination with question why you want this ? maybe there is some other solution

Comment: `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().didCrashOnPreviousExecution()`

Answer (score 1):

It's not too hard as you just want to know if it crashed. Not anything like why is crashed and other things. You can just use this:

```java
if(FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().didCrashOnPreviousExecution())){
   // the app crashed the previous time it was opened. 
} else {
   // the app did not crash the previous time it was opened.
}
```