# what does it take to re-create bugs from user's Android devices?

Tags: android

I've recently published my very first app to Play Store. I asked a friend to download and test it and it crashed on his phone. However, I have an exact phone as him with the same version of Android, and when I tested it the app runs without error. So what do I need to know about a device to re-create the bug?

Comment: Without knowing more about the crash (a log would be helpful) it is impossible to provide a good answer to this question.

Comment: This question is far too vague and broad in scope. There is no single thing you can be told to look at, and this isn't a *tutor me in debugging my apps* site.

Comment: @O.O.Balance is there anyway I can receive a log about a crash from user's device?

Comment: Like the other two comments without logs we cannot answer...but once same thing happened to me, that time my friend did not give app permissions..and I did not check for permissions..one of many possible causes.

Comment: @duyanhhoang check the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application

Answer (score 0):

So I've just figured out that Google Play Console there is a feature called Pre-launch report which give you the log of the bugs from user's devices, it is under Release Management tab on the left of the web page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a developer then can not re-create bugs because you would test with best-cases of app.You should test with worst-case scenario.
I will recommend to use a professional Tester to test your application. He/She must find out the bugs.