# Android app crashed. I can't get into the main interface at all

Tags: android, crash

I have a problem when I clicked my app, but the app crashed. I can't get into the main interface at all. The problem only appeared on some phones.

Error message:

```
04-02 14:53:45.806 1006-2162/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x30200000 cmp=com.excegroup.community.office/com.excegroup.community.MainActivity bnds=[23,374][187,539]} from uid 10029 from pid 2274 on display 0
04-02 14:53:45.807 1853-2981/? I/SLService2: [Monitor]---------[] t [com.excegroup.community.office] f []
04-02 14:53:45.809 1006-2162/? I/vivo_debug_ActivityManagerService: initSplitService intent = Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x30200000 cmp=com.excegroup.community.office/com.excegroup.community.MainActivity bnds=[23,374][187,539] }, r = ActivityRecord{77c7469 u0 com.excegroup.community.office/com.excegroup.community.MainActivity t47}
04-02 14:53:45.818 1006-1105/? D/ViewRootImpl: hardware acceleration is disabled, fakeHwAccelerated = true, HardwareRenderer.sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, HardwareRenderer.sSystemRendererDisabled = false, this = ViewRoot{73dbcdd Starting com.excegroup.community.office,ident = 65}
04-02 14:53:45.823 308-308/? I/BufferQueueConsumer: [Starting com.excegroup.community.office](this:0x7fb1656000,id:383,api:0,p:-1,c:308) setConsumerName: Starting com.excegroup.community.office
04-02 14:53:45.824 308-308/? I/BufferQueueConsumer: [Starting com.excegroup.community.office](this:0x7fb1656000,id:383,api:0,p:-1,c:308) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1 height=1
04-02 14:53:45.827 308-308/? I/BufferQueueConsumer: [Starting com.excegroup.community.office](this:0x7fb1656000,id:383,api:0,p:-1,c:308) setDefaultBufferSize: width=720 height=1280
04-02 14:53:45.831 1006-2247/? D/PerfServiceManager: [PerfService] appBoostEnable com.excegroup.community.office 
04-02 14:53:45.832 308-3523/? I/BufferQueueProducer: [Starting com.excegroup.community.office](this:0x7fb1656000,id:383,api:2,p:1006,c:308) connect(P): api=2 producer=(1006:system_server) producerControlledByApp=false
04-02 14:53:45.832 308-3126/? I/BufferQueueProducer: [Starting com.excegroup.community.office](this:0x7fb1656000,id:383,api:2,p:1006,c:308) new GraphicBuffer needed
04-02 14:53:45.843 1006-2247/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 20972:com.excegroup.community.office/u0a202 for activity com.excegroup.community.office/com.excegroup.community.MainActivity
04-02 14:53:45.868 1872-3666/? V/SceneMonitor: noteUidSwitch:  the current app: com.excegroup.community.office uid: 10202
04-02 14:53:45.868 1872-4401/? V/SceneMonitor: MSG_ACTIVITY_SWITCH the current app is :com.excegroup.community.office = uid : 10202
```

Comment: try uninstall your app and then reinstall

Comment: if doesn't work then kindly attached your `AndroidManifest` code too

Comment: This is only the `logcat`, could you provide the error message, debug and deploy the app on the phone. Here is a way to capture an crash before the app dies, you could save the error then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application